# Explicit Locks vs Implicit Locks

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Is using Locks (`java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock`) instead of keyword `synchronized` + method `wait()` and method `notify()` totally the same?

Can I thread-safely program using locks (explicit locks) rather than implicit locks (`synchronized`)?

As of know I have always been using implicit locks. I am aware of the advantages given by the `Lock` interface implementation like methods: `isLocked()`, `getLockQueueLength()`, `getHoldCount()`, etc... however still the old school way (`wait()` and `notify()`) would have other limits other than not having those methods?

I am also aware of the possibility of constructing a lock with a (boolean fairness) parameter which allows lack of starvation.

Comment: Well, it's not *totally* the same, as if they where 100% identical, then the existence of one would be redundant ;-)

Comment: @Joachim Sauer Surely it would not be the first time a programming language had two identical ways of doing the same thing.

Comment: @Patashu: surely not. But it's unlikely that they'd add a second option so long after the first one if there weren't at least some advantages (such as the `isLocked()` method, ...).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, absolutely you can write thread-safe program using `java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock`. If you see any implementation of `java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock` like `ReentrantLock` internal implementation uses old  `synchronized` blocks.

**Lock implementations provide more extensive locking operations than can be obtained       using   synchronized methods and statements. They allow more flexible structuring, may have quite different properties, and may support multiple associated Condition objects.**

Adding to my difference the `synchronized` keyword has naturally built in language support. This can mean the JIT can optimise `synchronised blocks` in ways it cannot with `Locks`. e.g. it can combine `synchronized blocks`.**synchronized** is best for a small number of threads accessing a lock and `Lock` may be best for a high number of threads accessing the same locks . Also `synchronized` block makes **no guarantees** about the sequence in which threads waiting to entering it are granted access.

Answer (score 5):

Locks and `synchronized` blocks have the same semantics and provide the same guarantees from a Java Memory Model perspective. The main difference is that Locks provide more control (such as with `tryLock` or when asking a lock to be fair etc.) which allow for a more flexible and fine-grained lock management.

However, when you don't need those additional features, it is better to use a plain old `synchronized` block as it reduces the room for error (e.g. you can't "forget" to `unlock` it).